# Append data to a global array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

In my app I have created a global array and access it in different classes, but when I am appending data to the array in different classes, I am getting only the last appended data. My code is:

```
struct Vehicle {
    var name: String
    var location: String
    var price: String
    var owner: String
}


class GlobalArray {
    static let shared = GlobalArray()
    var Vehiclecollection = [Vehicle]()
}



class home{

    func addVehicleOne(){

        Vehicle1 = Vehicle(name: "Bus", location: "Delhi", price: "25.5", owner: "Bean")
        var VehicleInfo = GlobalArray.shared.collectionArray
        VehicleInfo.append(Vehicle1)


    }
}

class addVehicle{

    func addVehicleTwo(){
        Vehicle2 = Vehicle(name: "car", location: "mumbai", price: "2.5", owner: "sean")
        var VehicleInfo = GlobalArray.shared.collectionArray
        VehicleInfo.append(Vehicle2)
        addVehicleThree()
    }
    func addVehicleThree(){
        Vehicle3 = Vehicle(name: "bike", location: "bangalore", price: "1.0", owner: "mark")
        var VehicleInfo = GlobalArray.shared.collectionArray
        VehicleInfo.append(Vehicle3)

        print("vehicles are \(VehicleInfo)")

    }
}
```

When I am running the code I am getting the result as:

```
vehicles are Vehicle(name: "bike", location: "bangalore", price: "1.0", owner: "mark")
```

Why am I not getting all the data in the array? Why am I getting only the last appended data? Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Arrays are *value types.* `var VehicleInfo = GlobalArray.shared.collectionArray` makes a *copy* of the array. You append only to that copy.

Comment: Yes i got it now. Thanks @Martin. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a reference to the global array and appending to it you need to set it back:

```swift
var VehicleInfo = GlobalArray.shared.collectionArray
VehicleInfo.append(Vehicle3)
GlobalArray.shared.collectionArray = VehicleInfo
```

or simply do:

```swift
GlobalArray.shared.collectionArray.append(Vehicle3)
```